# Gradle Peer not authenticated OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space

Tags: exception, android-studio, gradle, out-of-memory, peer

I have spent a lot of time with Android Studio 1.3 to be able to run a project. I faced so many problems so I want to put them here in one place so others can benefit from it and save their time.

- Android peer not authenticated
- Android Studio Gradle Issue: OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
- Gradle Could not HEAD https://..pom > peer not authenticated

I'll answer all those questions

Answer (score 0):

Android Studio 1.3 (64bit) on Windows 8 (64bit)

1) Install Java 8 (64 bit) and Uninstall all other, remove paths of old java

2) go to cmd and type "java -version" it should print the 1.8 version information

3) Go to `Environment Variables` and define two variables

- `_JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true`
- `JAVA_HOME C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51`

4) Open Android Studio (close project if any) Project Defaults -> Project Structure and set Java and Android Path

[image: Project Structure]

5) in your settings.gradle only include projects that you require e.g: `include ':library-projects/android-az-progressbar', 'az-sample-trunk'`

6) if you have huge project then you need to define those options under your project `.gradle` file `android { dependencies {`

```
dexOptions {
        jumboMode true
        incremental true
        preDexLibraries false
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
```

7) Now go to `C:\Users\{your_user}\.gradle` and make a new file named "`gradle.properties`"

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Settings specified in this file will override any Gradle settings
# configured through the IDE.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# The Gradle daemon aims to improve the startup and execution time of Gradle.
# When set to true the Gradle daemon is to run the build.
# TODO: disable daemon on CI, since builds should be clean and reliable on servers
org.gradle.daemon=true

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
org.gradle.parallel=true

# Enables new incubating mode that makes Gradle selective when configuring projects. 
# Only relevant projects are configured which results in faster builds for large multi-projects.
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:configuration_on_demand
org.gradle.configureondemand=true

#org.gradle.jvmargs=-XX\:MaxHeapSize\=256m -Xmx256m
```

8) Now Restart your computer and if needed Invalidate cache / restart your Android studio from file menu